make request from a static IP address to an API in AWS
I have an API that I need to host in AWS that makes requests to an API that requires IP whitelisting. In other words every request I make from my AWS server/service must have the same IP, or an IP whitelisted range of IP addresses.
My current (incorrect strategy) is as follows:
Global Accelerator -> Application Load Balancer -> API Gateway -> Lambda
This doesn't work because the Lambda does not have a static IP address, I've also had a hard time determining the range of IP's from which the requests are emanating.
I believe I could setup an  EC2 instance with a public static IP, but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this. Our infrastructure team at my day job handles this in the banking sector so I know this is a solved problem, and I think it has something to do with NATed IP addresses BUT I'm just going to hand wave at this idea as I don't understand it very well.
Any insight is greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time in reading/considering this!

First search result for "aws lambda static ip" -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/generate-a-static-outbound-ip-address-using-a-lambda-function-amazon-vpc-and-a-serverless-architecture.html

You are correct -- your choice is to run on an Amazon EC2 instance in a public subnet with an Elastic IP address (which is a static IP address that doesn't change), or put the AWS Lambda function in a private subnet of a VPC, with a NAT Gateway in the public subnet (extra costs apply), and an Elastic IP address assigned to the NAT Gateway. Price-wise, they are very close (due to the costs of a NAT Gateway), so it really comes down to your scalability needs and preferred architecture. Oh, and I don't think you need a Load Balancer in front of an API Gateway.

You need to run your Lambda functions inside private subnets of a VPC. Then, you give it egress internet connection using NAT Gateways hosted in the public subnets. NAT Gateways have static IP addresses and you whitelist these IP addresses in the API that you are calling.
Here's a detailed guide to implement it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/generate-a-static-outbound-ip-address-using-a-lambda-function-amazon-vpc-and-a-serverless-architecture.html

Thank you for guiding me to the right information. That guide was super simple to follow, and I really didn't have to spend any time fighting with AWS for this.
